# MATLAB: Subsetting one array by values of a second

Tags: matlab

I basically have two columns (arrays): column A represents a continuous stream of data across points in time (e.g. blood pressure rising and falling), while column B represents onset of an event (e.g. a shock or a deep breath). Column A has values for every cell, while column B only has values at a time point where an event occurred, which represent codes for the onset of different kinds of events (e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for 5 kinds).

What code can use the values in column B to subset data in column A (say collect all data from any time points between an event 1 and 2, and event 1 and 3, or event 1 and 4)? Basically, I'm trying to pull out the values for only certain time period segments, and store them in a cell array.

**Example:**

**What I have:**

Array A: 10, 12, 13, 20, 15, 16, 14, 9, 8, 11, 12, 15, 14

Array B: 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2

```
 *(where in Array B, 1 and 2 are events--say a showing a cue and a subject 
 responding to that cue--and I want the data between a 1 and a 2)*
```

**What I want:**

(New) Cell Array C: [12, 13] , [9, 8] , [15,14]

```
 *That is, it's grabbing the data from Array A, based on what falls between 
 1s and 2s in Array B, and storing them into cells of Array C*
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post a minimal example with small arrays and the desired output, so we can understand what you need

Comment: @LuisMendo corrected, sorry for that newbie mistake

Comment: @LuisMendo Ooph, sorry, I hope that after the 2nd edit, what I'm getting at is more clear. Yes, cell array.

Comment: _collect all data from any time points between an event 1 and 2_ In your example `C`, you are including the first point in some cases, but not in others; besides, `A` and `B` have different lengths. Can you clarify?

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry about that. I fixed the errors you mentioned. Hopefully that's clearer. In more words: I am saying once a "1" occurs in Array B, for Array A take the values that come after the 1, ending with the value that corresponds to 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way:

1. Find the indices of starts and ends. This can be done using `strfind`, which also works with numeric arrays.
2. Use those indices to build the result with a loop.

```
ind_start = strfind(B, [1 0]); % Or: ind_start = strfind(char(B+48), '10');
ind_end = strfind(B, 2); % Or: ind_end = strfind(char(B+48), '2')
result = cell(size(ind_start));
for k = 1:numel(ind_start)
    result{k} = A(ind_start(k)+1:ind_end(k));
end
```